# Removing wheel housing liner - Understanding instructions

Tags: trim

I need to take part of the front wheel housing liner out to gain access to the windscreen washer system. I have a set of instructions:
[image: Instructions]

Regarding the section at the bottom, titled "Vehicles with auxiliary heating", **what does the part "you must make the cut-out" mean?**

Is it perhaps a bad translation and just means that if you have this heater it will look like this, or are you literally expected to cut part of it away?

**Car:**  2012 Audi S3 Sportsback (8P chassis)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions for cutting the piece out of it for the Auxiliary Heater are for when you are installing a new (or replacing rather) the wheel housing liner. You just need to follow the instructions for removal, not for modification, even if the Auxiliary Heater is present.

Comment: Perfect, seems kind of obvious now that I think about it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, if your car has the auxiliary heater, then you will have to remove that piece of plastic (?) 70 by 50 mm to clear pipes (probably). If you do not have that auxiliary heater, then the parts will fit with no other modification.

Comment: So if my car does already have the auxiliary heater, those pieces of plastic will already be removed? I suppose the easiest way might be to check